# Delta two-handle still leaking on hot side

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, valve, hot-water, delta

So, I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what. I have a delta two-handle fixture in my bathtub and it was steadily dripping from the faucet, so I thought I could fix it myself. I purchased a 5-pack of 3S-2H/C stems, seats, and springs from Home Depot because it made the most economic sense, and figured since I had the 5 pack, that I should replace both sides. The cold side has been doing fine since, however, the hot side continues to develop a leak. I'll replace the spring, seat valve (may not be the correct term) and stem on the hot side. When I turn the main water back on, there's no leak. However, if I turn the hot on and back off, it develops a leak, and this happens: [image]

Like I said, on the cold side, everything is fine and I followed the exact same process on both sides. Can someone tell me what I've done wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Wow, it seems that the rubber seal (seat) is not being fully pressed down (or not staying fully down) in its proper position on top of the spring.

Make sure that the spring is right-side up (narrow end up) and that the retainer nut is fully tightened, to hold the stem all the way down.

Secret tip- use *plumber's grease* (petroleum jelly, in a pinch) to lubricate the seat and bottom of stem and threads on the retainer nuts. That will help the bottom sealing surface of the stem glide smoothly over the seat without catching on it. On the nut, it will help ensure you truly have it screwed down all the way.